# VLCj to record video - no audio and no motion in slave

Tags: video, record, vlcj

I've written the simple program below based on the VLCj test files. I would like to view the video and have it save to file with the audio. I've managed to play with the options now so that a file saves with good video. However, the image in the frame doesn't move and the video that's saved has no audio.

```
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.internal.libvlc_state_t;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.discovery.NativeDiscovery;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.videosurface.CanvasVideoSurface;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.x.LibXUtil;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.version.LibVlcVersion;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;

public class Capture {

    private final JFrame frame;
    private final JPanel contentPane;
    private final Canvas canvas;
    private static MediaPlayerFactory factory;
    private static  EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private static  CanvasVideoSurface videoSurface;
    private static String libvlcDir;
    private static boolean discovered;
    private static Capture capture;
    
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        
       libvlcDir = "/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib";
       NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), libvlcDir);

       LibXUtil.initialise();
       
       capture = new Capture();            
        
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                capture.start("qtcapture://0x1a11000005ac8509");
            }
        });
    }

    public Capture() {
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setBackground(Color.black);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.black);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame = new JFrame("Capture");
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(50, 50);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        
        factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        mediaPlayer = factory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
        videoSurface = factory.newVideoSurface(canvas);

        mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(videoSurface);
    }

    private void start(String mrl) {
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(frame);

        File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Videos");
        dir.mkdirs();

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss");
        String fileName = dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/Capture-" + df.format(new Date()) + ".TS";
        System.out.println(fileName);
        // Tweak the options depending on your encoding requirements and audio
        // capture device (ALSA is not likely to work on Windows of course)
        
        //String[] options = {":sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=4096,scale=1,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=file{dst=" + fileName + "},dst=display}", ":input-slave=alsa://hw:0,0"}; /original options - does not work on mac    
        String options = ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=1024,scale=1,width=360,height=300,acodec=mp4a, aenc=fdkaac,ab=256,channels=6,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=file{dst=" + fileName + "},dst=display}";
        
        mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl, options); //Records but no audio - also doesn't play in window (still image)
        
        //mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl); //Just plays in window (no recording)
    }
    
    
    public static boolean setupVLC(){
    //Open and read VLC directory from settings file
        String msg = "";
        discovered=false;
        //If file doesn't exist, then guess
        File temp = new File(libvlcDir); 
        String os = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
        if(!temp.exists()){
            discovered = setupLibVLC();
            if (discovered){
                //update settings if found
                String tempDir = NativeLibrary.getInstance(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName()).toString();     
                tempDir = tempDir.substring(tempDir.indexOf("<")+1,tempDir.lastIndexOf("/"));
                libvlcDir = tempDir;
                System.out.println("VLCdir = " + libvlcDir);
            }             
        }else{
            discovered=true;
        }
        //If still can't find it, ask for pointer to it
        temp = new File(libvlcDir);
        if(temp.exists() || temp.isDirectory() || discovered){
            NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), libvlcDir);
        }else{
            msg = "Can't find correct libraries in "+libvlcDir+" Please select the file.";
            findDllFolder(msg);
            //If still not found then ask for directory  
            NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), libvlcDir);
            try{
                System.out.println("libvlc version = " + LibVlcVersion.getVersion().toString());
                discovered=true;
            }catch(java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError err){
                msg= "You may be using the wrong version of VLC. Can't find correct libraries in "+
                                libvlcDir+
                                " Please select the file.";
                findDllFolder(msg);
            }catch(java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError err){
                msg  = "Can't find correct libraries in "+libvlcDir+" Please select the file.";
                findDllFolder(msg);          
            }
        }
        //Final throw of the dice to test the work above
        try{
            System.out.println("libvlc version = " + LibVlcVersion.getVersion().toString());
            discovered=true;
        }catch(java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError err){
             discovered = false;
        }catch(java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError err){
            discovered = false;
        }
        return discovered;
    }
       public static void findDllFolder(String msg){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog( null );
                if ( result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ){  
                    libvlcDir = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString();
                    if(System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Mac")){
                        libvlcDir = libvlcDir + "/Contents/MacOS/lib/";
                    }else{
                        libvlcDir = libvlcDir.substring(0,libvlcDir.lastIndexOf("\\"));
                        libvlcDir = libvlcDir.replace("\\", "\\\\");
                    }
                    System.out.println("VLCdir = "+ libvlcDir);

                }
    }
    private static boolean setupLibVLC() {

        discovered = new NativeDiscovery().discover();
        
        // discovery()'s method return value is WRONG on Linux
        try {
            LibVlcVersion.getVersion();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error in setupLibVLC");
        }
        return discovered;
    }
}
```

The error messages I get when running are:

> x264 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX
>
> x264 [info]: profile High, level 2.1
>
> x264 [info]: final ratefactor: 19.03
>
> x264 [info]: using SAR=10/9
>
> x264 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX
>
> x264 [info]: profile High, level 2.1
>
> x264 [warning]: invalid DTS: PTS is less than DTS
>
> x264 [warning]: invalid DTS: PTS is less than DTS
>
> x264 [warning]: invalid DTS: PTS is less than DTS
>
> [0x7f90bb2456c0] main vout display error: Failed to resize display
>
> [0x7f90bb2456c0] main vout display error: Failed to set on top
>
> [h264 @ 0x7f90b4064020] mmco: unref short failure
>
> [h264 @ 0x7f90b4064620] mmco: unref short failure
>
> [h264 @ 0x7f90b4063a20] mmco: unref short failure
>
> [h264 @ 0x7f90b4063a20] mmco: unref short failure

Any help would be much appreciated! Also, if there's a "cleaner" way to tidy up my "SetupVLC" code then I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When transcoding like that, you need to invoke release() on the media player when the media is finished so that native buffers are properly flushed and the file is properly closed.

Comment: Thanks. I've put that in for when the frame closes. However, the video still does not play in the mediaPLayer (it's a still image) and the recorded video has no audio. I also get an error message "Invalid memory access of location 0x11891f9b0 rip=0x7fff92d60250". What am I missing?

Comment: Caprica, is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Whenever you transcode anything, I would always get it working in vlc first before you even consider vlcj. That will highlight any fundamental problems. In principle when you have it working in vlc it should work in vlcj.

Comment: Thanks, that's how I got to this point. I tried multiple combinations of codecs to even get the video to record using VLC before porting to VLCj. Do you know what settings are best for recording video and sound on a mac using the inbuilt hardware?

Comment: Any ideas? I'm struggling to get a video+audio capture working in Java … open to other options… ???

Comment: No, none of the combinations of settings seemed to work - is there anything I could be missing? Any extensions that could be installed?

Comment: Perhaps VLC can't record audio from Mac (inbuilt hardware at least): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKF77xJ9E7U